# Let function return while other function finishes using threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function that modifies data and returns it to the user after modifying. At this point that is the information the user needs so I want to return it ASAP, but I need that modified_data to make calls to an API and upload data it to a DB, but this can be done in the background. Is there a way to have `modify_data()` return while letting `get_more_data()` finish?

I tried using threading, but it waits until `get_more_data()` returns before returning modify_data. I've also considered placing both into seprate threads in a parent function but I need `modify_data()` to generate the data for `get_more_data()` first.

```py
import threading
def modify_data(data):
    #modify data... example
    modified_data = [item+1 for item in data]
    th = threading.Thread(target=get_more_data(set(modified_data)))
    th.start()
    return modified_data

def get_more_data(data):
    #call api for more data
    #upload to DB
```

Comment: Your `target` needs to be a callable, not the result of having already called the function -- e.g. `target=lambda: get_more_data(modified_data)`

Comment: And missing that causes `get_more_data` to run in the *current thread*, not the new one. The new thread isn't doing anything. The behavior you're looking for is already how threads work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
th = threading.Thread(target=get_more_data(set(modified_data)))
```

you are executing the `get_more_data` method to get the target.
Try

```
th = threading.Thread(target=get_more_data, args=(set(modified_data),))
```

If you want to learn more about this, take a look [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: ahh that makes sense, instead of passing in the function as the target I'm actually passing in the result of calling the function. Thanks!